# How to read Excel in onedrive which can not be downloaded in python?

Tags: python, onedrive

I am now asked to read the excel file from onedrive in python, however, these files can not be downloaded.

Comment: you can use one drive package [https://pypi.org/project/python-onedrive/]

Comment: So if you cannot download or access the file how are you going to process and read the file in a python script? Please show some code what you alread tried to solve the problem.